# How to create a foreign key referencing one column in a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, composite-primary-key

I have two tables Catalog and CatalogIndex

catalog has the following columns

```
DN
PID
PURL
Desc
```

where the two columns DN, PID are part of the composite primary key for this table.

CatalogIndex has the following columns

```
PID
PItem
PVal
```

PID and PItem are part of the composite primary key for CatalogIndex table.

I want to add a a foriegn key to CatalogIndex on PID column that refernces PID in Catalog table.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **cannot** reference only parts of a compound primary key (one of the many drawbacks of compound PK - it gets really messy to reference them).

You need to reference **the key, the whole key and nothing but the key** (so help you Codd :-) ).

The only other option would be to create a new, `UNIQUE INDEX` on those columns you wish to reference (if they are indeed unique on their own) and then use that unique index to reference that subset of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a more normalized schema, with a separate table that has a PK on PID column. Your request is a smell that indicates imperfect database design.